# jquery code working in JSfiddle but not locally

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

This is in continuation to my first question.  I found out the code does work properly in JSfiddle when I copied and pasted it there.

I spent hours, and I still can't figure out why the exact same code doesn't work when I open it in my browser from the text editor (html file on my computer).

Here is the JSfiddle link:   http://jsfiddle.net/MhmC7/

```
  var C = $("#a20 option");
  C.on('mouseenter', function () {
  var V = $(this).val();

$("#" + V).addClass("hover");
})

C.on('mouseleave', function () {
var V = $(this).val();

$("#" + V).removeClass("hover");
})
```

I did link the html file to jquery library like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

I have no idea what the problem is. thanks a lot.

i was asked to add all my script tags in order so here they are:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>


   <!-- Include the DropDownCheckList supoprt -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ui.dropdownchecklist.js"></script>


    <!-- Apply dropdown check list to the selected items  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#a1,#a2,#a3,#a4,#a6,#a5,#a7,#a8,#a9,#a20").dropdownchecklist( { icon: {placement: 'right', toOpen: 'ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s'
                                        , toClose: 'ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n' }
                                        , maxDropHeight: 200, width: 220
                                        , groupItemChecksWholeGroup: true
                                        , textFormatFunction: function(options) {
                                            var selectedOptions = options.filter(":selected");
                                            var countOfSelected = selectedOptions.size();
                                            var values = "";
                                            for (i=0; i< selectedOptions.size(); i++) {
                                                if (selectedOptions[i].text != "")
                                                                           values += selectedOptions[i].text; 
                                                                           values += "; ";
                                            }
                                            switch(countOfSelected) {
                                                case 0: return "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Everybody</span>";
                                                case 1: return selectedOptions.text();
                                                case options.size(): return "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Everybody</span>";
                                                default: return values;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        , onItemClick: function(checkbox, selector) {
                                            //alert("value " + checkbox.val() + ", is checked: " + checkbox.prop("checked"));
                                        }
                                  });
    });






     </script>

    then, the last one is the script with the function in question, appearing right  before the </body> end tage, like so:

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var C = jQuery("#a20 option");
    C.on('mouseenter', function(){

    var V = $(this).val();
    $("#"+V).addClass("hover");
    });

   C.on('mouseleave', function(){
  var V = $(this).val();
  $("#"+V).removeClass("hover");
   }); 

 });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you include the script in your local project? You would need to put it inside a document ready handler or put the script at the end of the body so that it is not executed until the elements you try to manipulate exist. (In your fiddle you have selected the `onDomready` option from the drop-down under "Frameworks & Extensions".)

Comment: have you wrapped your code inside document.ready..?\

Comment: yes, I did. this piece of code is part of a huge html file with lots of jquery. i made sure every piece of jquery code is inside document.ready.

Comment: OK, but your fiddle doesn't have lots of jQuery, so maybe the problem isn't even with this code but is with some other part of your code that you don't show. What happens if you try only the above code in your local project? And do you get any JavaScript errors reported in your browser's console?

Comment: i tried to separate only that code in an html file and it still doesn't work. sorry, but how do i check for javascript errors? and if i do have js errors, how come it works perfectly in jsfiddle?

Comment: You can use the browser error console to check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things you should check:

1. Check the browser error console or debugger console to see what errors are reported.  If there are errors, they will probably indicate what is going on.
2. Your jsFiddle has set your script to run `onDomready` (setting on the left side of the jsFiddle).  If the code in your page is in the `<head>` section of your page or in the `<body>` section before your HTML, then the code would be running too early before the DOM elements are present and would not work.
3. Your code in your page needs to be encapsulated in `<script>` tags, but that is not necessary in the jsFiddle because code in the script section is automatically interpreted as script in a jsFiddle.
4. Double check that you are include jQuery appropriately in your page and that it's being included before you try to use it.

To get to the debug console...

In Chrome: right click on an element in the page and choose Inspect Element.  In the window that opens click on the word Console in the menu/tab bar.  Read any errors or warnings in the debug console window.

In Firefox: Install the Firebug extension or open the Web Console via the menus.  After installing the Firebug extension, right click on the page and click on Inspect Element with Firebug.  Click on the Console tab.  You may then need to hit reload for the browser page (with the Firebug window now open) to see the console errors for that page.

In recent versions of IE:  With your page open, hit F12.  When a window opens, click on the console tab.  In IE11, this is a graphic along the left side of the window that looks like a rectangle with a > prompt in it.  In other versions of IE, the UI for getting to the console is different.

Here's [an article](http://www.livejournal.com/support/faq/400.html) that covers how to get to the error console in these and other browsers.  There's a wealth of other information via a Google search for "browser error console" if you need more help.

Comment: i moved the code to the <body> after the html, and it is within the <script> tags. how do I check the error console, sorry to ask?

Comment: @user3384928 - error console instructions are in my answer now.  Google will also give you lots of other help if you just search for "browser error console".

Comment: ok, here is something VERY strange - when I add this jquery library to the head :   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs  /jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">   it screws up my select options dropdown lists. they are supposed to be dropdown lists with checkboxes, but when i add that library to the top of the html document they turn into non-checkbox lists...jesus

Comment: @user3384928 - Please focus on the main task.  What does that change have to do with getting your custom javascript to work?  One question/issue at a time please.  In your jsFiddle your select is not a dropdown with checkboxes either, but I don't want to discuss that issue now at all.

Comment: yeah, that's ok, i found out that if i put that library before the other libraries it doesn't mess with the checkboxes. sorry for all the information. i thought it might be related, but i guess it's not. anyhow, still not working so i will try to go over the error console like you suggested and report back.

Comment: i get this error:     "TypeError: C.on is not a function
 

                       C.on('mouseenter', function(){"                            that's the only error it gives me.

Comment: (i don't know what it wants me to do)

Comment: @user3384928 - That probably means that your var `C` is not a jQuery object and thus does not have a `.on()` method.  This could be either because jQuery is not properly installed or something else is overriding the `$` symbol that jQuery normally uses.  Please add to your question every script tag that you have in your page in the exact order in which they appear.  You can also try using `var C = jQuery("#a20 option");` instead of `var C = $("#a20 option");` in case jQuery is there, but something else is overriding the definition of `$`.

Comment: @user3384928 - also, please make sure that every `<script>` tag has a matching `</script>` tag to close it.

Comment: ok, i edited the question with all the <script> included, in order. thank you for your patience.

Comment: @user3384928 - your first problem is that you have two versions of jQuery.  Why do you have that?  What you need is one version of jQuery and the one that is compatible with the version of jQueryUI you are using.

Comment: can you please be more specific? i don't have any technical understanding of these things whatsoever, so i don't know what you mean by saying i need the compatible version. how would i know what that is? The 1.8.3 version i added because that's the javascript version that appeared on JSfiddle where the code worked. all the other "src=" ones below i copied from a source code which enables the drop down list plugin. i cannot delete any of those or the plugin won't work. i added the  1.8.3 version thinking it might make the hover effect work, but it didn't.

Comment: @user3384928 - ANY time you use a jQuery plug-in like jQuery UI or whatever your dropdownchecklist thing is, you MUST read the documentation for that plug-in and understand EXACTLY which versions of jQuery it works with.  You must either find a single version of jQuery that works with all your plug-ins/add-ins OR you have to do significant custom programming to make your site work with multiple versions of jQuery at the same time.  You can't just throw a bunch of things together like you've done without doing any research on jQuery version compatibility.  Go do the research on your plugins.

Comment: @user3384928 - you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) that jQueryUI 1.8.13 is compatible with any version of jQuery after 1.3.  Per [this page](https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/), dropdown-check-list is no longer supported.  The most recent version was compatible with  jQuery 1.6.1 and jQuery ui 1.8.13.  If I was building something, I probably wouldn't use something that is no longer supported unless I was willing to develop it myself going forward.  The gist of all this is that you should be safe with jQuery 1.6.x and jQuery ui 1.8.13.  Remove jQuery 1.8.3.

Comment: @user3384928 - FYI, I knew nothing about any of these versions a few minutes ago.  10 mins of Google searching found all the info.

Comment: there is only ONE plugin, only the dropdown list thing, and it works fine. all the other jquery code on my page works fine. it's just this hover effect thing that doesn't work. don't you think it would be much more simple to use an alternate code for the hover effect that would work with the version i already have?? i am not trying to be a technical expert, but only to present a concept.

Comment: what i mean is - it would be much easier to figure an alternate code than to figure out the different version compatibility.

Comment: @user3384928 - jQuery UI is also a plugin and consumer of jQuery so you have two things to consider compatibility of.  Get rid of the jQuery 1.8.13.  One version of jQuery ONLY.  If you want to go back to your question and describe what "hover" thing is not working, then maybe someone can help you with that.

Comment: I want to thank you again for your patience.                       The first piece of code that appears in my question (see top of the page) IS the hover effect(mouseenter over the options menu), which works in JSfiddle(to which i also provided a link). there should be an alternate code for that. are you saying that the 1.8.13 and the 1.6.1 are both plugin? they are both working together for the same functionality of the dropdown, so i don't think i could get rid of either.

Comment: @user3384928 - HOW MANY TIMES do I have to tell you?  Remove the 1.8.13 version of jQuery.  It's a duplicate of the 1.6.1 version of jQuery and may cause problems.  You CANNOT include two versions of jQuery in the same page without all sorts of custom programming to isolate one from the other.  For reasons I don't understand, you refuse to read and understand what I write.  I've said this now at least FOUR times.  I doubt this will fix your problem, but it will keep from making it worse which you did when you added the 1.8.13 version of jQuery.  Sorry, but I don't think I can help any more.

Comment: and how many time do i have to tell YOU - the 1.8.13 and 1.6.1 were included because that's exactly how they appeared in the sourcecode that i used, which works. i found out that only if i remove the huge function which makes the dropdown list work, only then the hover effect works. therefore, as i suspected, the best solution would be an alternate code for the hover effect. so if you can't help me with that, we definitely don't have a solution.